# Drag and Drop links into a form input box using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an input box that I would like to drag and drop links into using jQuery. My goal would be to click the link drag/drop it into the input box and have it populate the image tag if its a link to an image or the href tag if its a link to a file.

Is this possible? Can anyone think of any examples for something like this? The more answers the better so please post what worked for you.

Thanks in advance!

Here is some more information for people who are interested:
The drag and drop feature relies on browsers supporting File.API.

More information:

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/

http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Let me know if this was helpful and or if I can add more information. Thanks all!

Comment: So you want to drag a link from a page into an input box on the same page, and create an `<img />` or `<a></a>` tag where?

Comment: I was hoping to have the tag populate into the input field/box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems simple enough; at least in my browser (Chrome) dragging a link into a input/textarea and having it populate with the URL that the anchor references is default functionality; therefore the following should do the job.

```
$("input").change(function() {
  if($(this).val().substring($(this).val().length-3, $(this).val().length) == 'jpg') { 
    $("a img").attr('src', $(this).val())
  } else {
    $("a").attr('href', $(this).val())
  }
})
```

Obviously you'd want to expand the code to support further filetypes and I'm sure there are better way to identify whether the URL refers to an image or not, but this is a good starting point.

If this doesn't serve your exact needs you might want to consider what event to bind on the input box in question; `focus` could also be a viable option?

Comment: Thank you Steve, I will give this a shot on Monday (fingers crossed).

Comment: Works in FF but for some reason not in IE. I saw another question that states IE does not have the dragging of links into text area enabled. 

I still need to figure out how to wrap the links in img src= and <a href= tags. Sigh... Going to be a long day =]

Comment: I don't have a solution as to how to get inputs to populate from a drag in IE off the top of my head. I have however provided you with the latter pretty much. My example takes the assumption you have existing elements to change; if you don't then try the following: `$("<a/>").attr('href', $(this).val()).text($(this).val()).appendTo('body')`. That creates an anchor and then appends it to the body tag of your page.